# Sanity check on my d3.line generator, I cannot see the error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot figure out why my d3 line doesn't work. Maybe you can see the issue. My summaryData is an array of objects of the following format:

```
const summaryData = 
    [
        { 
            x0: Date Sun Dec 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), 
            x1: Date Sun Jan 07 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), 
            value: 4.15 
        },
        {...}
    ]
```

I define my line generator:

```
const chartLine = line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.x0))
    .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)));
```

where:
`const yValue = d => d.value;`
`xScale` is timeScale (correctly defined - used elsewhere) and `yScale` is a linearScale (also correctly defined and used elsewhere).

I render my line like this (in JSX):

```
{
   summaryData.map((d, i) => (
       <g key={i}>
           <path fill="none" stroke={"black"} strokeWidth={1} d={chartLine(d)}/>
       </g>
   ))
}
```

That code results in line 0x0:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"></path>
```

I use this code in another project with no issues, I cannot figure out what is off. Can you help?

Comment: Your line generator, `chartLine`, should take an array of data.  From your code snippet it looks like you are calling it point by point.

Comment: Oh, so intead of a map, I should just pass summaryDate? Thanks a lot, I'll try it and update you on the outcome!

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If you add this as as an answer I will accept it :)